# Trigonometric Manipulation with inequality:$x^2 \cos \theta - x(1 - x) + (1 - x)^2 \sin \theta > 0.$

Tags: trigonometry

> Find all angles $\theta,$ $0 \le \theta \le 2 \pi,$ with the following
> property: For all real numbers $x,$ $0 \le x \le 1,$
>
> $$x^2 \cos \theta - x(1 - x) + (1 - x)^2 \sin \theta > 0.$$

I am not exactly sure how to solve this problem. A friend gave me the suggestion to use the substitution $\sin^2(y)=x,\cos^2(y)=1-x$. Then, $\sin^4(y)\cos(\theta)-\sin^2(y)\cos^2(y)+\cos^4(y)\sin(\theta) > 0$. I tried to exploit symmetry by dividing by $\sin^2(y)\cos^2(y)$ to get $\tan^2(y)\cos(\theta)+\cot^2(y)\sin(\theta)>1$. I am not sure how to continue from here. Anything I tried from here was fruitless. What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: I'd write it as a quadratic in $x$ with coefficients which are functions of $\theta$ and then consider the discriminant of this quadratic.

Comment: @MichaelCohen But in this case we have an additional contraint $x\in[0,1]$ so that method may not get all the possible $\theta$

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Actually that's true of course. I didn't read the question properly!.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$f(x)=x^2 \cos \theta - x(1 - x) + (1 - x)^2 \sin \theta > 0\Leftrightarrow$$
$$f(x)=x^2(\sin \theta+\cos \theta+1)-x(1+2\sin \theta)+\sin \theta>0.$$

Let's look at the discriminant,
$$\Delta=(1+2\sin \theta)^2-4(\sin \theta+\cos \theta+1)\sin \theta$$
$$\Delta=1-2\sin (2\theta)\to -1\le \Delta\le 3.$$

First case of solutions,

- $\Delta<0$ and $\sin \theta+\cos \theta+1 >0.$

Second case,

- $\Delta\ge 0$: $x_1\le x_2$ are the roots of $f(x)$,

a) If $\sin \theta+\cos \theta+1 >0$ then $x_2\le0$ or $x_1\ge 1$;

b) If $\sin \theta+\cos \theta+1 <0$ then $[0,1]\subset[x_1,x_2]$.